# python int( ) function

Tags: python, int

The code below shows error if a decimal *(eg. 49.9)* is sent to `next` variable. Can you please tell me why? Why does `int()` converts it into an integer?

```
next=raw_input("> ")
how_much = int(next)
if how_much < 50:
    print"Nice, you're not greedy, you win"
    exit(0)
else:
    dead("You greedy bastard!")
```

If I dont use `int()` or `float()` and just use:

```
how_much=next
```

then it moves to "else" even if I give the input as `49.8`.

Comment: You probably want to say `how_much = int(float(...))` or `how_much = int(round(float(...)))`.

Comment: small side note: `next` is not a good choice for a var name, as there is a build in function `next()` since 2.6 in python

Comment: you are here because of this. http://learnpythonthehardway.org/book/ex35.html

Answer (score 12, accepted):

As the other answers have mentioned, the `int` operation will crash if the string input is not convertible to an int (such as a float or characters). What you can do is use a little helper method to try and interpret the string for you:

```
def interpret_string(s):
    if not isinstance(s, basestring):
        return str(s)
    if s.isdigit():
        return int(s)
    try:
        return float(s)
    except ValueError:
        return s
```

So it will take a string and try to convert it to int, then float, and otherwise return string. This is more just a general example of looking at the convertible types. It would be an error for your value to come back out of that function still being a string, which you would then want to report to the user and ask for new input.

Maybe a variation that returns `None` if its neither float nor int:

```
def interpret_string(s):
    if not isinstance(s, basestring):
        return None
    if s.isdigit():
        return int(s)
    try:
        return float(s)
    except ValueError:
        return None

val=raw_input("> ")
how_much=interpret_string(val)
if how_much is None:
    # ask for more input? Error?
```

Comment: If i dont use int() or float() and just use how_much=next then it moves to "else" even if i give the input as 49.8

Comment: Because you are comparing strings then: `"49.8" < 50`

Comment: I had a typo and forgot to put the `None` in that second one. Just fixed.

Comment: Bare except is evil.  `except ValueError` would probably be a better idea.

Comment: @Kevin, if I were wrapping a larger block of code, or a user-defined function, I would agree. But in this particular case, I feel like it is sufficient to simply catch any exception that the builtin `float()` could raise.  Either I can convert the value, or a can't.

Comment: @jdi: Anything can raise `KeyboardInterrupt`.  The user can hit Ctrl+C at any time.

Comment: Ok, if you are worried, in this example, of potentially missing a `KeyboardInterrupt` in the span of the time it takes to call `float(s)`, then I can update the example :-)

Answer (score 5):

`int()` *only* works for strings that look like integers; it will fail for strings that look like floats. Use `float()` instead.

Comment: Why doesent int() converts the input into integer?

Comment: Because it can't be interpreted as an integer.

Answer (score 2):

Integers (`int` for short) are the numbers you count with 0, 1, 2, 3 ... and their negative counterparts ... -3, -2, -1 the ones without the decimal part.

So once you introduce a decimal point, your not really dealing with integers. You're dealing with rational numbers. The Python float or [decimal](http://docs.python.org/library/decimal.html) types are what you want to represent or approximate these numbers.

You may be used to a language that automatically does this for you(Php). Python, though, has an explicit preference for forcing code to be [explicit instead implicit](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0020/).

Comment: If i dont use int() or float() and just use how_much=next then it moves to "else" even if i give the input as 49.8

Comment: Well thats because `how_much` then becomes a string. I wouldn't expect that to even work.

Answer (score 2):

```
import random
import time
import sys
while True:
    x=random.randint(1,100)
    print('''Guess my number--it's from 1 to 100.''')
    z=0
    while True:
        z=z+1
        xx=int(str(sys.stdin.readline()))
        if xx > x:
            print("Too High!")
        elif xx < x:
            print("Too Low!")
        elif xx==x:
            print("You Win!! You used %s guesses!"%(z))
            print()
            break
        else:
            break
```

in this, I first string the number `str()`, which converts it into an inoperable number. Then, I `int()` integerize it, to make it an operable number. I just tested your problem on my IDLE GUI, and it said that 49.8 < 50.

Comment: your code produce the right result but its way too long for that task.

Answer (score 1):

Use [float()](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#float) in place of [int()](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#int) so that your program can handle decimal points. Also, don't use `next` as it's a [built-in Python function, next()](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#next).

Also you code as posted is missing `import sys` and the definition for `dead`

Comment: Why doesent int() converts the input into integer?

Comment: @ShubhamAgrawal It can't convert something with a decimal point to an int, it needs to get a string that looks like an int.

Comment: @ShubhamAgrawal Can you tell us your goal and why `float()` would not be an acceptable solution?

Comment: float() is an acceptable solution. If i font use either float() or int() then why doesent python recognise the input's type and check if its lesser or greater than 50?