# Django Migrate : TypeError: int() argument must be a string or a number, not 'User'

Tags: django, django-models, django-authentication, django-migrations

I have applied some changes to the model.py and when I applied `makemigrations` it worked fine. But after that, the `migrate` command gives the following error.

`TypeError: int() argument must be a string or a number, not 'User'`

Here is the Traceback:

```
Operations to perform:
Synchronize unmigrated apps: staticfiles, messages
Apply all migrations: admin, mess, contenttypes, auth, sessions
Synchronizing apps without migrations:
Creating tables...
Running deferred SQL...
Installing custom SQL...
Running migrations:
Rendering model states... DONE
Applying mess.0003_auto_20150821_1912...Traceback (most recent call last):
File "manage.py", line 10, in <module>
execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 338, in execute_from_command_line
utility.execute()
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 330, in execute
self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 393, in run_from_argv
self.execute(*args, **cmd_options)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 444, in execute
output = self.handle(*args, **options)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/management/commands/migrate.py", line 221, in handle
executor.migrate(targets, plan, fake=fake, fake_initial=fake_initial)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/migrations/executor.py", line 110, in migrate
self.apply_migration(states[migration], migration, fake=fake, fake_initial=fake_initial)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/migrations/executor.py", line 148, in apply_migration
state = migration.apply(state, schema_editor)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/migrations/migration.py", line 115, in apply
operation.database_forwards(self.app_label, schema_editor, old_state, project_state)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/migrations/operations/fields.py", line 62, in database_forwards
field,
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/backends/sqlite3/schema.py", line 179, in add_field
self._remake_table(model, create_fields=[field])
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/backends/sqlite3/schema.py", line 77, in _remake_table
self.effective_default(field)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/backends/base/schema.py", line 211, in effective_default
default = field.get_db_prep_save(default, self.connection)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/models/fields/related.py", line 1956, in get_db_prep_save
return self.related_field.get_db_prep_save(value, connection=connection)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/models/fields/__init__.py", line 710, in get_db_prep_save
prepared=False)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/models/fields/__init__.py", line 977, in get_db_prep_value
value = self.get_prep_value(value)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/models/fields/__init__.py", line 985, in get_prep_value
return int(value)
TypeError: int() argument must be a string or a number, not 'User'
```

Here is my `models.py`:

```
from django.db import models
from django import forms
from django.contrib.auth.models import User as auth_user 
class Student(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(auth_user) #rollno
    rollno = models.IntegerField()
    password = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    fullname = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    email = models.EmailField()


class Banking(models.Model):

    student = models.OneToOneField(Student)
    breakfastcount = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    lunchcount  = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    dinnercount = models.IntegerField(default=0)

class Meal(models.Model):
    mealname=models.CharField(max_length=20)
    mealcost=models.IntegerField(default=0)
    MEALS = (('BREAKFAST','Break Fast'),
             ('LUNCH','Lunch'),
             ('DINNER','Dinner'))
class Booking(models.Model):
     student=models.OneToOneField(Student)
     date = models.DateField( editable=True )
     meal=models.CharField(max_length = 20, choices=MEALS)
```

Can anybody help me with this `TypeError` ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The trackback says the error comes from get_prep_value in init.py, so can you add that piece of code?

Answer (score 2):

Solved the issue. This has been a bug in `code.Django` under ticket #23454
**https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/23454**

But this bug has been closed due to insufficient information.

I created a new app and replaced the files with the older one and `makemigrations` as well as `migrate` ran successfully.

I think this issue arises if we try to change the Django Auth system after first migrate.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

> What this means ?

Your function `get_prep_value` is returning this

```
return int(value) -> Type of value is User object
```

> But it should be of type ***int or string(only if its a valid integer
>   enclosed in double quotes like "1" else an exception would be raised)***

*Since you have not shared that function, i would suggest the following things*

1. Check what you are passing into the value.
2. Use `type (value)` before your return statement so you know what you are having inside the value variable.

> *Read here about the int() which might be confusing you here*

[python int( ) function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12020821/python-int-function)

Comment: It is an inbuilt method I guess, since I haven't coded `get_prep_value`. By the way, the issue is solved. Thanks for the effort.